# postgres escape characters

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres, how can I escape the RTF syntax in the **MESSAGE** parameter of the where clause?

```
select count(*) 
from communicationoutgoingmessagescheduledetails 
where email='chris.green@waynesreaves.com' 
and message='{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{\*\listoverridetable}{\stylesheet {\ql\cf0 Normal;}{\*\cs1\cf0 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\cf0 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\cf1 Hyperlink;}}\splytwnine\sectd\pard\plain\ql{\cf0 first }{\b\cf0 paymen}{\b\cf0 t bold }{\cf0 rem}{\cf0 inder}\par\pard\plain\ql{\ul\cf0 se}{\ul\cf0 cond PAYMENT }{\b\ul\cf0 reminder}\b\ul\par}' 
and succeddful=-1 
and senttime::timestamp::date='2/7/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

### Update

this is the error I am getting

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal LINE 4: and message='{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}{\c...

HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'. 
ERROR:  invalid Unicode escape LINE 4: and message='{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}{\c...

HINT:  Unicode escapes must be \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX.
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid Unicode escape SQL state: 22025 Hint: Unicode escapes must be \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX. Character: 124
```

### Update 2

This is the code I am executing to get the result set from PostgreSQL:

```
string sql = "select count(*) from communicationoutgoingmessagescheduledetails " +
                        "where email='" + email + "' ";

        if (message != string.Empty)
            sql += String.Format("and message='{0}' ", message);

        if (subject != string.Empty)
            sql += String.Format("and subject='{0}' ", subject);

        sql += "and successful=true " +
        "and senttime::timestamp::date='" + date.Date + "'";


        System.Data.IDbConnection connection = ORGen.Access.Config.Instance.Connection;
        IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        bool retVal = Convert.ToInt16(command.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 ? true : false;
        connection.Close();

        command = null;
        connection = null;
```

Comment: Please *always* mention your PostgreSQL version, and the language you're using to send the SQL.

Comment: Sorry about that.  PostgresSQL 9.0.4 and C#.Net.

Answer (score 26):

On PostgreSQL 9.3 or newer and haven't manually changed the `standard_conforming_strings` setting, you don't have to escape anything except single quotes, which you double like this:

```
'this is a single quote: ''. '
```

If you're on an older version, set `standard_conforming_strings` to `on` in `postgresql.conf`, or double backslashes and use the `E''` string notation:

```
E'{\\rtf1'
```

This is all explained [in the lexical structure section of the user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

However, you should really be using your language's PostgreSQL client driver to send **parameterized statements** that take care of escaping automatically. Failure to do so can lead to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) holes - see [this site](http://bobby-tables.com).

Since you are using C# with npgsql, you probably want http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html . More detail is given in the [npgsql user manual](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html).

Comment: No need to escape single quotes in modern Postgresql if dollar quoting is used like in `$$this is a single quote: '.$$`

Comment: Could you define modern with a version number above something please?